# Meteor: Loading all page resources in the background

Tags: caching, meteor

When someone navigates to my Meteor app, I would like the home page to be loaded first, rendered, and displayed. And then as soon as this is done (the user can start clicking around), all the other resources and databases for all pages of my app are loaded (cached) in the background to LocalStorage (as much as can fit), so that all the pages, images, etc, of my app will appear instantly when navigated to.

What's the no-brainer convention for doing this in Meteor? Is there a package?

And secondly, how do I indicate which resources I want to be highest priority in the background loading queue? For example, how do I make sure that a "splash page" and its images shows up right away?

Answer (score 2):

Meteor apps are, by design, single-page sites. If you view-source on a deployed Meteor app, for example http://docs.meteor.com, the `<head>` always looks something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/5a6084946b1bc47e30e45c05bdecb13536a2dc64.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
__meteor_runtime_config__ = {"meteorRelease":"galaxy-follower-5","ROOT_URL":
"http://docs.meteor.com","ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX":"","serverId":
"964b34dc-ffbb-b860-a313-9eedca254d83","DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL":
"ddp+sockjs://ddp--****-docs.meteor.com/sockjs"};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/3353c2b059d42f3fe42e0d5eba87882b955d7cbe.js">
</script>
```

That .css file is *all* of your app's CSS, concatenated into one file; and that .js file is *all* of your app's JavaScript, including all of your templates, concatenated into one file. That's just the way Meteor is designed, and it's not something you can change without delving deep into Meteor's source and rewriting some major chunks.

The only suggestion I have for you is to have your homepage served by something else, such as an Apache or Nginx server, which really does serve up just the bare minimum that you're after; and fetches the above .css and .js files and preloads them. Use a [router package](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) in your Meteor app, and take care that all the links in your homepage point to routes that are defined in the Meteor app. You can also speed things up a bit by separating out and loading from a CDN or your Apache/Nginx server any resources not directly needed by Meteor—images, additional CSS, external JavaScript like libraries—and having those preloaded by your non-Meteor-hosted homepage.

Finally take a look at [meteor-external-file-loader](https://github.com/davidd8/meteor-external-file-loader). It's designed for loading external JavaScript libraries on the fly in Meteor apps, for example loading Google Maps only on the pages where you're actually showing maps. I'm not sure if it can be used to load JavaScript that's core to your app like templates, but if your app is so large that you're thinking of splitting it up anyway then presumably there are parts of your code that you can separate into packages like your own custom JavaScript libraries, which can then be loaded dynamically from your Apache/Nginx server using meteor-external-file-loader.